# Typescript not applied to files for my NPM module

Tags: typescript, npm, webpack

I've written an NPM module which I install in an app. However I get an error that suggests that Typescript isn't being applied to the .ts files in the NPM. When I run the NPM as its own app it works fine.

The line in question assigns a type to a const:

```
const usersService: UsersService = new UsersService()
```

Here's the error I get:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (5:14)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

The app the NPM is installed to has its own .ts files which work fine.

Comment: Did you compile before publishing to npm?

Comment: No I didn't compile it, this is my first npm. But thanks for the tip!

Comment: If you don't compile first then consumers need to configure loaders for modules in node_modules which is generally an antipattern.

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense. I've also just discovered that some modules use declaration files (.d.ts) during this process.